# Does deleting a app from simulator remove files?

Tags: ios

I was storing some files in the `Documents/` folder of my application using archiving.
Then, I removed the application from simulator.
It seems the files that were inside the `Documents/` folder got removed too.
Is it the expected behaviour? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is an expected behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This applies to the simulator and the iPhone.

Because of the sandbox, all the application's documents are stored on the application's bundle.
So obviously, removing an app also removes the documents.

So this is the expected behaviour. Otherwise, you'll just have tons of junk data taking space on your phone.

**-- Edit --**

To answer the question you asked in the comments, the easiest way IMHO is to have a directory containing your files elsewhere.
Then you can symlink the `Documents` directory in the app's bundle so it points to the other location. This way, when deleting the app from the simulator, it won't delete the files.
Repeat the process when installing again.

Comment: out of curiosity: how do I store something on simulator or iPhone that persists even if uses deletes app from Simulator?

Comment: Thanks I asked second question out of interest if I need it I will look for more info about this. ps. I think the directory for applications bundle and Documents directory are *separate*, although they are both stored in the sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you remove the app from simulator then it will definitely remove your data because you have given the simulator's path for storing that data. It will stay until you have your app in your simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you delete the app, its sandbox gets removed too.